# How to extract json api through go to extract stargazers_count of a repo?

Tags: json, go

stargazers_count of https://api.github.com/repos/openebs/openebs using go language by extracting it through json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an [example](https://play.golang.org/p/nb1WwQS_bV2) (completely neglecting error handling):

```
request, _ := http.Get("https://api.github.com/repos/openebs/openebs")
defer request.Body.Close()
bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(request.Body)

var apiResponse struct {
    StargazersCount int `json:"stargazers_count"`
}
json.Unmarshal(bytes, &apiResponse)

fmt.Println(apiResponse.StargazersCount)
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nb1WwQS_bV2)

Comment: can you  pls send me the whole code cause i am new in go and i am finding it difficult to place this block properly. @Emile

Comment: @LokeshSingh I've added a Playground with everything included.

Comment: Can you say me how to display it on browser?